# How to show image on Camera View programmatically in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures

I am working in app, using Vuforia Library in which i am using camera(device camera). I want to render 2d Texture(any .png or .jpg) on camera defined its coordinate and its size. I tried but my app always getting crash. I don't know whats wrong i am doing. Please help me on That this will be great for me.

`string tempPath = "/Assets/Images/119642-samsung-galaxy-note-2-picture-large.jpg";`

```
Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(400,350);
Resources.LoadAssetAtPath(tempPath, typeof(Texture2D));
renderer.material.mainTexture = tex as Texture2D;
```

Here above is what i am doing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there is no need to use `Resources.LoadAssetAtPath`. According to the docs:

> Returns a resource at an asset path (Editor Only).
>
> This function always return null in the standalone player or web
>   player. This is useful for quickly accessing an asset for use in the
>   editor only.

Assuming `renderer` is the correct renderer for the GameObject you want to display on, this code *should* work, assuming your `tempPath` is correct:

```
WWW www = new WWW("file://" + path);
yield www;
Texture2d texture = www.texture;
texture.Resize(400, 350);
renderer.material.mainTexture = texture;
```

You have to use a `WWW` to get the actual file, then assign that to the actual Texture2d. Then you can resize it to whatever width/height you like, then assign that to the mainTexture.

If this works, please uprate and accept! Else tell me what is incorrect with it!

Comment: Thanks so much. I did this, but it show image which is stuck with camera. I don't need this I want to show image at specific location and it show stuck with specific location not with camera. How can i so this?

Comment: @josh Umm, what do you mean? Can you be more clear? Does the image render to the camera instead of the gameobject? Could you give a screenshot?

Comment: Yes this image should stuck with game object. Like what I am doing I am making app for Geocaching so when user come at specific location and direction then i will show Image which should be stuck with specific location.